# umbraco examine index rebuild exception

Tags: umbraco

I am trying to rebuild my internal index. I am using tools such as the [examine dashboard](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/examine-dashboard) that clear the index and re-run indexing.

For some reason this always results in an exception and I am left with no index. This is probably due to "ghost" content in the database or something like that.

This is the exception:

```
[SqlHelperException: Umbraco Exception (DataLayer): SQL helper exception in ExecuteXmlReader]
   umbraco.DataLayer.SqlHelper`1.ExecuteXmlReader(String commandText, IParameter[] parameters) in C:\tfs\xo\rotiseme.xo.gr\Indice\umbraco_4.7.1\umbraco\datalayer\SqlHelper.cs:272
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document.importXml() +185
```

Any ideas how I can recover from this?

Answer (score 1):

The internal index is usually stored in ~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Internal/Index/

You could delete all files from this folder and then republish your site. This should trigger the re-indexing of your site.

Comment: Hi ,In Umbraco 5.0.1 we have indexpath as  "App_Data/Examine/HiveIndexSet"

Comment: @bhargav This is a v4.x issue.

Comment: actually i was trying to implement the same in v5,can you suggest where I can find an updated version of implementing Umbraco examine.Thanks